# android google play service error during app build on mac

Tags: android, cordova

I just created a new android project with cordova and when i loaded the project in android studio. i got the below error. 
I have updated my google play services but still given me this error.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':processDebugGoogleServices'. > Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.0.1.
```

Answer (score 0):

Can try using latest version

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.2.0'
```

And Also check if you have

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    // ...
}
```

in upper `build.gradle` file